# GCM - 1 email registered at 2 devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM for my application. I have a situation which the flow:

1. I have two devices (Device A and Device B).
2. App installed in both device.
3. Device A logged-in (Email which registered in GCM server = abc@domain.com).
4. Device B logged-in using same email (abc@domain.com).
5. I tried to send message to abc@domain.com, but only device B receive the message.

So, how can I implement GCM so that both device A and B receive the message?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCM's [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications).

> With device group messaging, app servers can send a single message to multiple instance of an app running on devices belonging to a group. Typically, "group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user. However, a group could also represent a set of devices where the app instance functions in a highly correlated manner, such as a phone with a temperature control app installed, a smart thermostat, and an automatic window opener. All devices in a group share a common notification key, which is the token that GCM uses to fan out messages to all devices in the group.

You have to get registration tokens for each devices and also make `notification_key` which identifies the device group.

Device Group Messaging can register up to 20 devices. If you need more than 20 devices to receive the message you can instead use Topic Messaging.

Comment: Will make research on it. Thank you :)