# GCM Send notification to many groups

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implementing GCM for group messaging. My situation:

- Device A and B registered under GROUP 1.
- Device C and D registered under GROUP 2.

Referring to https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications, I can send notification to GROUP 1, but it is impossible to send to both group (GROUP 1 and 2).

Here's my code:

```
<?php
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'MyAPI' );

$notification_key = 'notificationKeyHere';

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'to'    => $notification_key,
    'data'  => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;  ?>
```

Code above works for sending to only one group.
So then later I tried:

```
$notification_key = array("nKey1", "nKey2");
```

The error produced:

```
Field "to" must be a JSON string: ["nKey1", "nKey2"]
```

So how can I alter my code so that both group can received the notification?

Comment: Currently, there is no direct way of sending to many groups as far as the documentation is concerned. What you can do is to individually send a [downstream message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream) to the devices involved. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511167/how-to-send-gcm-messages-to-multiple-devices-at-a-time).

Comment: Thanks for that. There's a problem when using "registration_ids". See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835663/gcm-1-email-registered-at-2-devices) @gerardnimo

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending messages to a single device use 'to'

```
 'to'    => $notification_key,
 'data'  => $msg
```

But if you are sending messages to multiple devices use 'registration_ids',

```
$ids = array("nKey1", "nKey2");
```

and send as

```
 'registration_ids'  => $ids,
 'data'              => $msg,
```

Comment: I got an error which is "NotRegistered" while using "registration_ids", but it is okay when using :"to" @yusuf-kartal

Comment: I think this answer solved your problem. For second (NotRegistered)problem below link has a detailed description http://stackoverflow.com/q/23470252/517134